# Blog and categories vs tags

Tags: discussion

So in the Wordpress software there are Categories and Tags.  Do we want to have some method to how we use these organizational methods?

I was thinking:

Category

- Tool Review
- Project
- Administrivia
- Introduction
- Misc Tips
- Work Guidelines

and then for the tags we can drill down more specifically, plumbing, electrical, carpentry, flooring, etc.
What do people think of this scheme?

Comment: Sounds good to me

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what Administrivia is supposed to be.   I prefer Tips & Tricks over Misc. Tips.  And how about Product Reviews over Tool Review (or even just "Reviews")

Comment: Administrivia would be something like this post: http://diy.blogoverflow.com/2012/01/holding-up-the-shovel/  Product review is good for me - is there space for a 'Technique review' or something like that as well?

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me as well. We can always extend the categories in the future if we get a new one, like the bloopers.